# Grep mac address separated by period

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I want to grep mac address separated by a period, but I don't know how to grep `4ddd.8a5b.080c VLAN 14` in this line:

For example:

```
Internet  192.168.15.24     0         4ddd.8a5b.080c  arpa   VLAN 14
```

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` will first match `VLAN 14` before extracting the columns needed

```
sed '/VLAN 14/ {s/.*0         \(.*\) arpa \(.*\)/\1\2/}' input_file
```